# How to subscribe to CloudMQTT using MqttDotNet or any other dot net client

Tags: c#, .net, mqtt

I have created new MQTT instance using https://www.cloudmqtt.com/ below are the details 
[image]

And below is my code I am using MqttDotNet as given on CloudMQTT website ( [https://www.cloudmqtt.com/docs-dotnet.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHAd2.png) ). Which gives error "Unable to connect to the broker"
        I am not sure how to connect to MQTT what should be the connection string how to use it with username and password.

```
  using System;
using MqttLib;

namespace Sample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting MqttDotNet sample program.");
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop\n");
            Program prog = new Program(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
            prog.Start();

            Console.ReadKey();
            prog.Stop();
        }

        IMqtt _client;
        Program(string clientId)
        {
            // string connectionString = "mqtt://m13.cloudmqtt.com:12644";
            string connectionString = "mqtt://moraasdrxf:_WaY_f_sLt8Efd@m13.cloudmqtt.com:12644";
            // Instantiate client using MqttClientFactory
            _client = MqttClientFactory.CreateClient(connectionString, clientId, "dhiraj", "dhiraj");
            // Setup some useful client delegate callbacks
            _client.Connected += new ConnectionDelegate(client_Connected);
            _client.ConnectionLost += new ConnectionDelegate(_client_ConnectionLost);
            _client.PublishArrived += new PublishArrivedDelegate(client_PublishArrived);
        }

        void Start()
        {
            // Connect to broker in 'CleanStart' mode
            Console.WriteLine("Client connecting\n");
            _client.Connect(true);
        }

        void Stop()
        {
            if (_client.IsConnected)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Client disconnecting\n");
                _client.Disconnect();
                Console.WriteLine("Client disconnected\n");
            }
        }

        void client_Connected(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Client connected\n");
            RegisterOurSubscriptions();
            PublishSomething();
        }

        void _client_ConnectionLost(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Client connection lost\n");
        }

        void RegisterOurSubscriptions()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Subscribing to mqttdotnet/subtest/#\n");
            //_client.Subscribe("mqttdotnet/subtest/#", QoS.BestEfforts);
            _client.Subscribe("dhiraj/test", QoS.BestEfforts);

        }

        void PublishSomething()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Publishing on mqttdotnet/pubtest\n");
            _client.Publish("dhiraj/test", "Hello MQTT World", QoS.BestEfforts, false);
        }

        bool client_PublishArrived(object sender, PublishArrivedArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Received Message");
            Console.WriteLine("Topic: " + e.Topic);
            Console.WriteLine("Payload: " + e.Payload);
            Console.WriteLine();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anybody please help me with this ??

Answer (score 2):

This is resolved. MQTT dot net implementation use tcp protocol to make connection to brocker 
connection string should be 
string connectionString = "tcp://m13.cloudmqtt.com:12644"